# Help for Windows to open the downloaded Ubuntu version

Tags: software-installation

I downloaded Ubuntu but Windows needs to know what to open it with. I am using a Vivaldi browser not Firefox.

Comment: See [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/a/152902/178692) - start at Step 3

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows 7, Windows 8, or Windows 10, just right-click on the .iso file you downloaded and select

```
Burn disc image
```

[image: Burn disk image]

Then just choose your DVD burner in the next dialogue box, put the blank DVD in the drive and burn your installation disk.